# Is it possible to convert between layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" and layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/img" according to a specific condition

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

**I drew this instead of XML so you can understand what I want**

[image]

If the `ImageView` was not opposite `ChipGroup` like `Screen 1` then I want to apply this `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"` inside `ChipGroup`, Otherwise apply this `app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/imgView"`

Is it possible to do it using `Barrier`, `Guideline`, or anything else?

I published the question before but does not take any attention, Is it possible to do that in Android? I searched a lot to find similar questions but I did not find anything.

> All components in the image above are inside `ConstraintLayout`.
>
> Every `ImageView` has a different height, So some images will be
> tallest than others.

Comment: Not so sure you should let your imageView resize itself, it could be problematic in future. My first advice would be to constrain the imageView so it doesn't resize. 

If this is still not what you want and want to still go with it, I do think you may have to do this from code, basically reading the image height and applying constraints on the ChipGroup from code manually

Comment: @Robin Sorry I was wrong when I said the height of the `ImageView` will be different for each image. The height of the `ImageView` will be one and this is attributes inside `ImageView` `layout_width="0dp" , layout_height="0dp" , layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1" , layout_constraintWidth_percent=".4"`. But if you can see green lines that are `MaterialTextView` and has `maxlines="10"` so sometimes the `ChipGroup` will be opposite the `ImageView` and sometimes not, According to number of the lines in `MaterialTextView`

Answer (score 1):

The constraint of a `view` can be changed programatically, using `constraintSet`

To set `chipGroup` end to `parent` end

```
val parent = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.parent) // constraint layout
val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
constraintSet.clone(parent)
constraintSet.apply {
    clear(R.id.chipGroup, ConstraintSet.END)
    connect(R.id.chipGroup, ConstraintSet.END, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.END)
    applyTo(parent)
}
```

To set `chipGroup` end to `imageView` start

```
val parent = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.parent) // constraint layout
val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
constraintSet.clone(parent)
constraintSet.apply {
    clear(R.id.chipGroup, ConstraintSet.END)
    connect(R.id.chipGroup, ConstraintSet.END, R.id.imgView, ConstraintSet.START)
    applyTo(parent)
}
```